# Update to the ROAM Large Scale Mesh LOD Method

Tags: unity, terrain, 3d-meshes, mesh, dynamic-mesh

I'm looking to create very large planetary terrain meshes. The most efficient and researched methodology I've seen so far was the [ROAM 2.0 Method](http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:21085/FULLTEXT01). However, this was written and published in 2005. **Does anyone know of a more up to date method for solving large, detailed mesh LOD transitions?**

Comment: I assume displacement from a heightmap. How about ... no meshes any more ? Have you already researched continous methods like for instance CDLOD by P. Strugar ?

Comment: What specific problem are you having with ROAM 2.0 that you'd like us to help you solve? "It's old" isn't a problem on its own — there are plenty of algorithms much older than 2005 that remain the best known solutions in their respective domains to this day. Do you have any evidence that this algorithm is not fit for your purpose? What criteria should we use to suggest improvements that would better serve your needs?

Comment: @DMGregory Sorry. I don't see anything in particular that would be a problem. I'm just looking for some preliminary information before jumping into it to only find out that there is a more up to date and accepted methodology to do the same thing.

Comment: That doesn't sound like the type of question StackExchange is particularly good at answering in a way that stands the test of time. Necessarily, new techniques will become popular as time goes on, and search engines are optimized for indexing the latest writings available — so researching that way is likely to get you fresher info. But newer doesn't always mean better suited to your use, so don't be afraid of implementing an old reliable solution if it works for you. You can post here if you identify a concrete problem with it you need our help solving or finding alternatives for.